# How to sum dynamic range?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
|3|5|0|4|0|9|6|
```

I want to sum dynamic  range and not sum if value 0.

Example.

1. sum  2 time range A1-G1  Result is 8.
2. sum  3 time range A1-G1  Result is 12.
3. sum  4 time range A1-G1  Result is 21.

how to coding in excel.

Comment: What difference does it make if zero is added to the total or not?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer does exactly what you want.

Comment: Can I help you further?

Answer (score 2):

To calculate sum of first `2` nonzero values in range `A1:G1` you can use following array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`):

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A1:G1,1,SMALL(IF(A1:G1,COLUMN(A1:G1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:G1))+1),2)))
```

For `3`, change `SMALL` function's parameter:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A1:G1,1,SMALL(IF(A1:G1,COLUMN(A1:G1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:G1))+1),3)))
```

Use `IFFERROR`, to check if there are enough nonzero elements:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(A1:INDEX(A1:G1,1,SMALL(IF(A1:G1,COLUMN(A1:G1)-MIN(COLUMN(A1:G1))+1),7))),"??")
```

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, cell `A5` will hold the number of 'dynamic' cells to sum. The 'dynamic' range grows to the size of `A5` where the zero values are not included in the size.

You can enter my formula in any blank cell that you like.

This is an array-formula and it must be confirmed with Control-Shift-Enter:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:G1,1,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(A1:G1,COLUMN(A1:G1)),ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,A5)))))))
```

When you enter values from 1 through 5 in cell `A5`, here is what the formula returns:

1 = 3

2 = 8

3 = 12

4 = 21

5 = 27

Be careful to not enter a number in `A5` larger than five, unless you increase the number of non-zero values in the source range.

The source range size can be increased by changing the four references to `A1:G1` in the formula.